# VB.NET MS Access: Data gets recorded even when Copies is 0 or -1

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am working on Library Management System using VB.NET linked with .accdb, and want to add If condition to this code, so when user click the borrow button and selected book copies available is 0, an error should appear and record will not be added to database.

```html
Try
            Dim ds2 As New DataSet
            Dim da2 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Copies FROM Book", con)
            If da2.Fill(ds2) Then
                Dim cb1 As OleDbCommand
                    cb1 = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Book SET Copies=Copies-1 WHERE ISBN=@ISBN", con)
                    cb1.Parameters.Add("ISBN", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = TextBox1.Text
                cb1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Book Borrowed Succesfully!")
            Else
                MsgBox(MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Oledb Error")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Two options. first, do then is a query to find how many copies of the book are available before update (Which you already have done btw). Second option, ExcuteNonQurey returns the number of records affected, inspect that and handle exceptions as required

Comment: `da2.Fill(ds2)` does not return a Boolean so it cannot be used in an `If`.

Comment: I don't know what overload of MsgBox you are attempting to use but `MsgBox(MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Oledb Error")` doesn't match any of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to select a single piece of data, the number of copies available for a single ISBN. You can use `.ExecuteScalar` for this. If Copies is greater than 0 we decrement the field. Notice that we use the same command, connection, and parameter.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function CheckCopies(isbn As Decimal) As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim sql = "Select Copies From Book Where ISBN = @ISB;"
    Dim AvailableCopies As Integer
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, New OleDbConnection(ConStr))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ISB", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = isbn
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        AvailableCopies = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        If AvailableCopies > 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Book SET Copies=Copies-1 WHERE ISBN=@ISB;"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            message = "Check out complete."
        Else
            message = "No copies available."
        End If
    End Using
    Return message
End Function
```